# Use jQuery Sortable with Dynamically added list (not just dynamic items)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can I make sortable work with a list that is dynamically removed and added? I don't mean that just the items are dynamic, but the complete list itself.

Should I just run this each time that I add the list back? Is there a way to avoid that?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#my_menu_list").sortable({
      stop: completed_sorting,
      items: 'li',
       delay: 150,
       distance: 5,
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

I have seen answers that ask about dynamically adding elements within the list. That's not my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding items dynamically/programmatically to jQuery-ui sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121650/adding-items-dynamically-programmatically-to-jquery-ui-sortable)

Answer (score 4):

After adding dynamic list, use below code to apply *sortable*  plugin to dynamic list.

```
$("#my_menu_list").sortable("refresh");
```

Purpose of above method is as below.

*Refresh the sortable items. Triggers the reloading of all sortable items, causing new items to be recognized.*

http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh

Comment: I get an error: Cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: First of all keep your initialization code and apply above code once you will add new element

Comment: I'm not adding a new element. The whole list (including the UL) is removed and brought back (ajax loaded page).

Comment: Kindly add your code which is used for removing or any kind of manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
     $(document).find("#sortable").sortable({
      cancel: ".unsortable"
     });

     $(document).find("#sortable").disableSelection();
     
     $( "#sortable" ).on( "sortstart", function( event, ui ) {
   $("#response").empty();
   $(document).find( "#sortable").sortable("refresh");

   jQuery(this).sortable("refreshPositions").children();
   $("#sortable").sortable("toArray").map(function(item,index){
    
    var text="Position:"+index+"- "+item+"<br/>";
    $("#response").append(text);
    
   })
   
  });

     $(document).on("change","input[type='checkbox']",function(event) {

   var id=$(this).closest('li').attr('id');

   if($(this).is(":checked"))
   {
    console.log("console log  ",id);
    $(document).find("#"+id).removeClass('unsortable');
    $(document).find( "#sortable" ).trigger( "sortstart");
   }
   else
   {
    var clone = $(document).find('li#'+id).html();
    $(document).find("li#"+id).remove();
    var li=$("<li/>");
    li.attr("class","ui-state-default");
    li.attr("id",id);
    li.append(clone);
    $("#sortable").append(li);
    $(document).find("#"+id).addClass('unsortable');
    $(document).find("input[name='"+id+"']").prop('checked',false);
    $(document).find( "#sortable" ).trigger( "sortstart");
    $(document).find("#sortable").sortable({
        cancel: ".unsortable"
       });
   }   
  });
  });
```

```css
.ui-draggable, .ui-droppable {
 background-position: top;
}
li{
cursor: move;
}
.unsortable{
cursor: no-drop;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul id="sortable" class="list-group">
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-1"><input type="checkbox" name="item-1" checked><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-2"><input type="checkbox" name="item-2" checked><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-3"><input type="checkbox" name="item-3" checked><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-4"><input type="checkbox" name="item-4" checked><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-5"><input type="checkbox" name="item-5" checked><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-6"><input type="checkbox" name="item-6" checked><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default" id="item-7"><input type="checkbox" name="item-7" checked><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```